# Why is VSCode undoing my saved changes after page refresh?

Tags: html, d3.js, visual-studio-code

Essentially what is in the title.

I am currently working with HTML and D3.js and often, I will make changes in the code, refresh the page, and find that the change did not have any effect. Not only that, but when I go back into VSCode, the values that I have changed will revert back. If I go into VIM and change the values, this does not happen and the page changes the way that I want it to.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: do you have your code in VM or docker?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm running the backend in Node and simply opening the html in Chrome. Though the things that I am changing are local and not in the backend.

Comment: Maybe your are editing the wrong project, like you have two different directory for the project and you are editing the wrong one in VS code.

Comment: There is only one directory for the project. It also wouldn't explain why the code in VSCode changes when I go back to it.

For example, I could change the font size from 12 to 15 in VSCode, refresh in Chrome, go back to VSCode, and the value will have changed back to 12.